# Converting standard normal distribution to skew normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $Z$ that is generated based on a standard, normal distribution which I want to transform to follow a skewed, normal distribution, say with skew $\alpha$, standard deviation $\sigma$, and mean $\mu$. I know that to convert $Z$ to a normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$ and mean $\mu$ I can use the transformation $\sigma Z+\mu$, but am unsure how to incorporate the skew factor. Any help would be much appreciated!

To be more specific, I have a program which generates values based on a standard, normal distribution. It has poor functionality, so will not generate values based on a skew normal distribution, so I would like to be able to take those data points and transform them individually. For instance, if I had skew $\alpha = 0$, then I believe I could achieve this by taking the given data point $x$ and applying $x \mapsto \sigma x+\mu$. I'm not sure how to do this for general $\alpha$ though.

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a skewed-normal distribution and then taking exponential (just like from normal to log-normal)?

Comment: @BGM - I've edited the original question to hopefully make it more clear. I'm not a statistician, so am not very comfortable with the theory.

Comment: The reason that I have the above comment is that log-normal distribution is inherently skewed, and I cannot find any interesting thing yet about "skewed log-normal distribution". However, skew normal distribution is quite common and have the shape parameter $\alpha$ in wikipedia too. So you need to provide a clearer definition for your terms.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working at this to see if I can make the question clearer. It's not obvious from the context of the work I'm doing, but perhaps I wanted normal distribution rather than log normal.